# Having a variable in a script with the result of qsTr or call a lot of times qsTr in QML

Tags: qt, qml, translation

This may seem like a dumb question, but I have a function where I have a for-cycle and I call `qsTr` function a lot of times, like this one:

```
function example() {
    var groups = []
    for (var g=0; g<io_data.length; g++) {
        groups.push( { "label": qsTr("I/O Group"),
                        "value": String(g+1),
                        "headers": [
                                    qsTr("Entry"),
                                    qsTr("Panel"),
                                    qsTr("Loop"),
                                    qsTr("Device")
                                ]
                     } )
    }
}
```

Of course according to the documentation `qsTr` is a function that gets the correspondent translation, so if I have a for-cycle that is too big I suppose that is a lot better in this case to have variables for each `qsTr` translation, like this:

`var ioGroupLabel = qsTr("I/O Group")`

what do you guys think?

Comment: So if I understand your question, you consider two options: Eating a bit of RAM to store your translations or burning your CPU to do the same translations again and again?

Comment: @jbh hehe i think the answer is simple, i just don't know how intensive is the qsTr function

Comment: Just profile it then - I found the tr functions to be quite slow and did what you suggest on a number of occasions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html):

The most common way of marking strings is with the qsTr() function. For example:

```
Text {
    id: txt1;
    text: qsTr("Back");
}
```

This code makes "Back" a key entry in the translation files. At runtime, the translation system looks up the keyword "Back" and then gets the corresponding translation value for the current system locale. The result is returned to the text property and the user interface will show the appropriate translation of "Back" for the current locale.

---

In your case, there will be 5 key entries created: "I/O Group", "Entry", "Panel", "Loop", "Device". No matter how much for-cycles you are doing in your source code.

---

In general, if you know that you can reduce amount of calls of specific function (e.g. `qsTr`) without much overhead -- just do it.

---

**UPD:** Regarding performance measurement, you can refer to [this project](https://github.com/troyane/StackOverflow-pro/tree/master/qsTrProfile).

This picture will show you how efficient is previous declaration instead of calling of `qsTr` (run with `testCount=9999999`).
[image]

Comment: Right only five keys created, but the function qsTr gets called there as many iterations of the for cycle there are, if i understand it well. So it's better to have variables that get the result of the qsTr and then use the variables on the for cycle. Thanks.

Comment: @Nmaster88 you are absolutely right. If you know that you can reduce amount of calls of specific function (e.g. qsTr) without any problems -- just do it :)

Comment: Just add UPD to answer: add code for testing optimized vs unoptimized. Results -- more than twice cheaper (in percentage).